# How does Kaladin confront Roshone?

Tags: cosmere, stormlight-archive

Throughout book 1-2 of the Stormlight Archives Kaladin talks about how he is going to confront Roshone back in his home of hearstone. Do we know how he ends up confronting him?

Comment: I think you know the answer to that. Do you just want to test whether the Future Works policy applies to serialized works?

Comment: @Adamant  no i never read tor's website, cough no i dont

Comment: You even know where the answer is. ;) I'm tempted to downvote for lack of research effort.

Comment: @Adamant - I wouldn't close for future works - technically it is released, and from an official source, but since this is just asking for a reading of the chapter and is pretty clearly aware of what's in there besides, definitely a downvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case anyone is unaware, while the actual release of *Oathbringer* is dated for Nov 17, Tor.com is releasing preview chapters (quite a lot of them actually) once a week leading up to the release.

Since our questioner clearly has no awareness of this, I will include a [relevant early scene](https://www.tor.com/2017/09/05/oathbringer-by-brandon-sanderson-chapters-4-6/) below.

> ...He reached over and held up the hair in front of Kaladin’s forehead. “Storms, boy. What did you do? Hit a lighteyes?”
>  “Yes,” Kaladin said. Then punched him.
>  ...
>  Roshone dropped like a felled tree.
>  “That,” Kaladin said, “was for my friend Moash.”

It doesn't go much beyond that yet.

> Wasn’t the whole point of what he had learned to keep him from doing things like this? He glanced at Syl, and she nodded to him.
>  *Do better*.